# App doesn't filter correctly echo's from server

Tags: java, php, android

I have created an app which sends and reads data from a server. It should react to the response it receives (the responses from server works correctly). The problems is that the code in the if-statement where I check this is never executed, the app always executes the code in the else block. My PHP code is:

```
<?php  
 require "init.php";  
  $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];    
 $user_pass = $_POST["user_pass"]; 
  $user_name = utf8_encode($user_name);
   $user_pass = utf8_encode($user_pass);
   $sql_query = "SELECT user_name FROM user_info WHERE user_name ='".$user_name."'     AND user_pass = '".$user_pass."' ;";  

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

  echo "Login Success..Welcome "; 

 }else{
 echo"null";

  }
 mysqli_close($con); 
  ?>
```

And this is my AsyncTask class:

```
public class SendLogData extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{


String serverURL = "http://192.168.1.105/myapp/login.php";
Intent startapp ;
private Context mcontext;
private String response;
private String error = null;
ProgressDialog alertDialog;


public SendLogData(Context context, Intent intent) {
startapp = intent;
 mcontext = context;
}

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {

alertDialog = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
 alertDialog.setMessage("Connecting to server");
}

  @Override
 protected  String doInBackground(String... params) {
 String username = params[0];
 String password = params[1];

try {
URL url = new URL(serverURL);
HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
client.setRequestMethod("POST");
client.setDoOutput(true);
client.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
bufferedWriter.write(data);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();
InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
String line = "";
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
{
    response = "";
    response+= line;
}
bufferedReader.close();
inputStream.close();
client.disconnect();
return response;

} catch (IOException e) {
error = e.getMessage();
}

 return null;
}

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 if (result.equals("null")){// This is were, the appp never actives the if, and goes right to the else
Toast.makeText(mcontext, "You dont have a account with us.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}else{
alertDialog.setMessage(result);
alertDialog.show();
mcontext.startActivity(startapp);
 }

  }
}
```

Note: as im not getting any error from the app, i cant debug it, and the logcat doesnt show anything relevant.

Comment: Take a look at your block beginning with "while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)" - do you really want to get just the last line out of the buffered reader?

Comment: Yes, i just want the echos that the server retrieves, i dont need to read anything else. The only problem is, if i recive "null" from the server, the app cant handle it, and goes right to the else block.

Comment: could you show the 'result' in a Toast as first statement in 'onPostExecute()'? BTW you can use inline debugging by writing your own Log entries --> android.util.Log

Comment: "result" shows the string "response" returned in the doInBackground. So if the server returns "Login Success..Welcome ", it will show up that text, and the same with the echo inside the else of the php.

Comment: please forgive my insisting: "will/ should show" or "does show"? after all, we're talking about making sense of unexpected behaviour. So where does the "null" get lost?

Comment: No, the null always appears if there is no user with that username and password in the database, and always shows up the "Login success...Welcome", if there is one. So the app is able to read perfectly what the server sends to it.

Comment: all right, the PHP part will send "null" to the smartphone. Meaning some bytes will make their way into your InputStream. You are writing "UTF-8" and reading "iso-8859-1". I'm not an expert on charsets but the comparison 'result.equals("null")' obviously is going wrong. - BTW I like bughunting and if some comments down the line you are asked to take this to chat I agree :)

Comment: Yes, the problem is the "if" inside the app, im completly sure, but i dont know what to do. I been with this problem 3 days now, i even thought to use json to send the data because i dont find any response. And about the chat, i cant beacuse i only have 11 points , i dont know if you can invite or something :(

Comment: about the chat - I' relatively new as well and AFAIK if we go on commenting there will be an automtically generated offer some time soon. About the "if": android.String is "UTF-16". So if the comparison fails maybe it's about encoding problems. I'm reading about that right now but it would help if you could test that Toast in the first line as a first shot

Comment: So , should i change "result" to UTF-16?

Comment: I think you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/

Comment: on the other hand, that solution doesn't seem to work for android :( But the CharsetDecoder class can. Reading on...

Comment: i still with the same problem, i have changed the inputStream to UTF-8 and still getting the same issues, but i saw that the bufferedreader returns a int, so i dont know i that unfluences the result

Comment: ok, empty the else in the php and tryed to use isEmpty() in the app, but im still having the same result, the if is never executed, so i supose, that the server retrieves something even if the buffereader dont read anything.

Comment: please take a look at my answer and try with the original PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    Charset myCharset = Charset.forName("iso-8859-1");
    // and I really hope the name is correct - maybe "ISO-8859-1"
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
           InputStreamReader(inputStream, myCharset.newDecoder()));

 // .. process your input here ...
 }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.e("DECODER", ex.getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: Didnt work either. I also tryed to get the lenght of "result" with "Toast.makeText(mcontext, result.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" but it crashes everytime, maybe im reciving a int, but the system handles it like a string.

Comment: @Droid - to make the second parameter a String (if that's the reason for the crash):  Toast.makeText(mcontext, " " + result.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: so... I'm really sorry but I can't reproduce your problem and I'm running out of ideas. If you don't mind I'll give up now. But I'll upvote your question and maybe someone else gets interested and can help you.

Comment: ok, in the lenght  its retriving me 9 while the word in the echo is "perro" and have only 5 letters, is there anyway to know what is retriving me?

Comment: try to write to Logcat by using 'Log.i("someTag", your_info_as_string);' You have to import android.util.Log. I don't know what Log will make of different encodings - gloss it all over or not - but it's worth a try.

Comment: the log shows me the same message from the server :"08-11 19:55:31.943  25060-25060/com.example.nik.picsy I/MyActivity﹕ perro" , with any changes, but lenght still shows me 9, im really desesperated at this moment :( haha

Comment: what about things like whitespace? carriage return, line feed etc.? try 'result.trim();'

Comment: how should i use trim()? i have tryed declaring it before the Toast, inside the LOG, and inside the Toast, but it doesnt says to me the white spaces or any of the things that you said.

Comment: it removes whitespace both at the beginning and the end of a string. - Are you really sure that your server will use ISO-... encoding?

Comment: Finally!!! im really aprectiate your help men!!! It finally works, i trimmed the data recived by the server like this:"result.trim().equals("perro")", and it actually works. Thanks you very much really, you really helped me a lot. But, i still dont know, why it was retriving me spaces with the echos.

Comment: happy you made it. If you like, write an answer and post it :)

Comment: I mean, you did almost everything, i think you should take the honor haha. But anyways, i have fixed the problem, but i still dont know what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, thanks to @0X0nosugar, who helped me a lot. The problem was, the data that the server was retriving, was coming with 4 spaces, so when i was reiciving "null" in the app, which have 4 characters, the app was reading it with 8 characters. So, with simply trimming the data, it will convert the 8 char string, into a 4 char string:

```
if (result.trim().equals("null")){
 Toast.makeText(mcontext, "You dont have a account with us.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}else{
alertDialog.setMessage(result);
alertDialog.show();
mcontext.startActivity(startapp);
}
```

Don't know if the problem of inflate the data with spaces is actually a problem of the PHP or Android, but at least trim() helps to fix it.

Comment: Sorry I was offline so abruptly - a call from real life ;-) Any way, I think we both "boldly went where we had not gone before" because I know PHP only because I read a book and don't have any out of the lab experience with androids talking to a webserver. And it was your idea to check the string length which - ok - made me think of white space. So we were a good team! You can wait a while if there's someone with a good explanation to your problem and if not then IMO you can make your answer the accepted answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway, see you over here,  hope we can work together sometime :) hahaah